# childbrowser with phonegap 2.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Since phonegap 2 window.plugins is no more usable but childBrowser still relies on that.
How can i call childBrowser plugin in a phonegap 2 project?

This was working fine in 1.9:

```
cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all download the latest Child browser from here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/8848e8dd7f0d93810eec49fb1124f6389c963b68/Android/ChildBrowser

Use the **2.0.0** version

The plugin creates the object window.plugins.childBrowser. To use, call one of the following, available methods:

```
  /**
    * Display a new browser with the specified URL.
    * This method loads up a new web view in a dialog.
    *
    * @param url           The url to load
    * @param options       An object that specifies additional options
    */
  showWebPage(url, [options])
Sample use:

window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com", { showLocationBar: true });
  /**
    * Close the browser.
    */
  close() {
Sample use:

window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
  /**
    * A user supplied call back which is run when the browser is closed.
    */
  onClose() 
Sample use:

window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();
  /**
    * A user supplied call back which is run when the browser location changes.
    * The method is called with the new location of the browser.
    */
  onLocationChange(location) 
Sample use:

window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange(location);
  /**
   * Display a new browser with the specified URL.
   * 
   * NOTE: If usePhoneGap is set, only trusted PhoneGap URLs should be loaded,
   *       since any PhoneGap API can be called by the loaded HTML page.
   *
   * @param url           The url to load
   * @param usePhoneGap   Load url in PhoneGap webview [optional] - Default: false
   */

  openExternal(url, [usePhoneGap])
Sample use:

window.plugins.childBrowser.openExternal("http://www.google.com");
```